# Magento automatically generate "core.XXXXX" file in server

Tags: magento-1.8

I got Magento running on my main root (It's VPS Server).

Everyday core.XXXXX files are generated automatically and site goes down. I got this message "Your maximum disk usage quota has been reached".

Now my host says he has no clue what they about and says Magento is doing it cause to him its only my site creating the core files.

Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/8vsmio

One thing i tried already is : https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/after-apache-upgrades-core-files-are-filling-up-public_html.73416/

Has anyone any knowledge to this? i searched magento but all i found is some termination of a service on host causing this.

Answer (score 4):

The files you are describing are core dumps and are a result of applications crashing on your server.

You can disable core dumps like this,

```
echo 'fs.suid_dumpable = 0' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

I'd change my hosting provider to one that knows what they are doing if I were you.

Comment: Sorry ! I am pretty much new here. Where should i place this code ?

Comment: Honestly, change hosting provider. If there were ever a time for someone to use a managed provider, yours is. If you don't understand the commands I've given you, you shouldn't be in charge of your own server.